# Writing script/program to automatically write-protect and aggregate each new spreadsheet in a Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to automate a process that is currently done manually:

There's a folder `/foo` in Google Drive, which contains Google Spreadsheets. Every time a new spreadsheet file is added to that folder:

1. The spreadsheet should be locked against any writes, i.e. become read-only
2. Have its values aggregated in a separate spreadsheet, i.e. the sum of cells A1:A10 in the new spreadsheet should be added to cell B2 of the aggregate spreadsheet.

I've never worked with any Google Sheets/Apps/Drive APIs before, so I'm not totally sure this is even possible. Specific questions I have:

1. Is there a way to trigger a script whenever a new sheet is added to a Google Drive folder?
2. Is there a way to write-protect sheets?
3. More generally, should this be done with Google Apps Script or Google Sheets API (i.e. external client)?

For example, I found the [Protection class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) in the Google Apps Script API, but I'm not sure if it has all the other features I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible via [Google Drive Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push).

Basically you'd write a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) and implement its `doPost()` method, [deploy the script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and then register the Web App's url as a webhook (via the [Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com) as described in the documentation on [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push)). Then you'd set up notification channels to watch for drive changes. When changes occur to the drive, data is sent to the web hook url and you can inspect the payload to see what has changed.

To write-protect a sheet you can set permissions on a file as documented in the [Share Files section of the Google Drive API guides](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing).